Copy text from remote headless Neovim server using local Neovim --remote-ui
I have a docker container running nvim --headless --listen 0:0:0:0:7777
I can connect to it successfully with nvim --remote-ui --server localhost:7777
There does not seem to be any built in copy ability from the headless server to the local TUI. When I use docker run -it to access the console of the docker container and run nvim inside, I am able to copy and paste to my local clipboard. But if I connect to the remote server using --remote-ui there is no clipboard support. I configured the headless neovim instance to use the OSC 52 clipboard, but that didn't help.
Is there something that I am missing? It seems that the nvim --headless and nvim --remote-ui instances should transfer yank operations between them.

As of now it’s a problem with neovim 0.10.0 the OSC52 logic is being processed in the backend part, so the TUI client can’t access the clipboard correctly. Relevant GitHub issue
